# How to catch when user doesn't have correct roles

Tags: symfony, user-roles

I have an symfony application that takes advantage of user roles to speed up development time. In my inexperience, I am coming across the issue that if they don't have the proper roles associated with their user, it redirects them to the login page, even if they are currently authenticated.

How would I go about overriding this behaviour, and keeping them logged in, just sending them to an information page telling them what actions they need to take to increase their role/privileges?

I currently have a provider set up like this to catch a `AccessDeniedException`:

```
  website.access_denied:
    class: %website.access_denied.class%
    arguments: [ @doctrine.orm.entity_manager, @website.website ]
    tags:
      - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: handle }
```

Then, in my `security.yml`, I have the `access_denied_handler` setup like so:

```
 firewalls:
    website:
        access_denied_handler: website.access_denied
```

And, finally, my class:

```
class AccessDenied implements AccessDeniedHandlerInterface
{
    public function handle(Request $request, AccessDeniedException $accessDeniedException)
    {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to use a login success handler to deal with your problem (see http://www.reecefowell.com/2011/10/26/redirecting-on-loginlogout-in-symfony2-using-loginhandlers/) it'll alow you to redirect a user after it's login depending on your choices (in your case their role) tell me if you need an exemple. Edit : Or maybe a request listener if you want that your control is effective on all your application

Comment: @Coussinky If JMax's problem is the same as mine, and I think it is, it's not just about redirecting at the login. The user needs to be redirected anytime they try to access a page that they don't have the role for, which could be well after the login as been successful. I.e. authorization not authentication